# Get value from json variable using windows powershell 5.1

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.1

I've got a JSON like this

```
[  
   {  
      "Param1":true,
      "Param2":0,
      "Param3":"OK"
      ...
      ...
   }
]
```

How can I get Param2 value, using powershell 5.1?
For now, I tried to get property names, but only get length

```
$jsondeconverted = $jsonOrig | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsonOrig .PsObject.Properties |
     Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
     ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Key : " $_
        Write-Host "Value : " $thisJSON."$_"
     }
```

**EDIT**
This is how I get my json

```
$jsonvar = '['+$jsonvar+']'
$convertedJson =  $jsonvar | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
$deconvertedJson = $convertedJson | ConvertFrom-Json
```

$deconvertedJson contains only length parameter and nothing more.

Comment: Have you tried `$jsondeconverted.Param2`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to look into the object (`$jsondeconverted`) rather than the string (`$jsonOrig`)

Based on your json Structure, you would access param2 in the following way `$jsondeconverted[0].Param2`

**Verifiable complete example**

```
$jsonorig = '[{"Param1":true,"Param2":0,"Param3":"OK"}]'
$jsondeconverted = $jsonorig | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsondeconverted[0].param2
```

Comment: I tried this and $jsondeconverted.Param2. These methods returned nothing.

Comment: @ВасяПупкин Then your problem is somewhere else I would think. Can you try the verifiable complete example I added ?

Comment: @Вася Пупкин: Your json is an array. You need to index it like @Sage Pourpre does. `$jsondeconverted.Param2`will not work.

Comment: @PalleDue     `$jsondeconverted.param2` also work and is equivalent to : `$jsondeconverted | Select -ExpandProperty param2`. In the simple object above, results would be identical using array index or not. Not using index could result in more than one values in a more complex object though.

Comment: @SagePourpre pls, see my edit. Verifable example works, but I can't make it work through code populated variable

Comment: @ВасяПупкин Check `$convertedJson` structure. Is it really what you show in your example ? Can you debug (F8)  `$jsondeconverted`  and look at the object ? You should see the structure there. Also, if you are building your json from code, rather than doing that, converting it to json forth and back, you should use a `[PSCustomObject]@{'HashtableKey'='Value}` to generate your PSObject directly. You can later on convert it to json if you need it in that way but you will save yourself the need to escape.